# Cookies set in Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage are ignored on redirects

Tags: winrt-httpclient

I'm using HttRequestMessage, and adding a cookie in an IHttpFilter as follows:

```
public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var c = new HttpCookiePairHeaderValue("SSOAutologonCertificate", "true");
    request.Headers.Cookie.Add(c);
    return InnerFilter.SendRequestAsync(request);
}
```

Using Fiddler I can see that the cookie is correctly added to the outgoing request. However, the reply is an auto-redirect. When fiddler captures that outgoing request, that cookie is no longer set in the http header - it seems to have been forgotten.

Is this expected behavior? Or a bug? If it is expected behavior, is there anything I can do to alter it?

If, on the other hand, I add the cookie to the Cookie collection on a HttpBaseProtocolFilter object, then everything works as expected, and the cookie is there for every auto-redirect query. Of course, while that will work for now, that totally defeats the purpose of a IHttpFilter. :-) This behavior was observed on a windows store app (running on Windows 10 tech preview).

BTW, I spent some time trying to figure out how to step into the .NET source for the Windows.Web.Http namespace, but nothing seemed to work (I can into other .NET source). Is there a special trick for these windows component files (the module is Windows.Web.winmd).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This was asked some months ago. Did you figure out what's happening? I'm starting down this path for conversion of our App to Windows.Web.Http.

Comment: I didn't, nor did I get a response. I basically had to encode my own recovery and forwarding code. :( That said, I've not tried looking at .NET Core or any of the more modern things since then, so it may be fixed in some modern version of the platform.